# Hypergeometric Function Value

Tags: sequences-and-series, hypergeometric-function

Wolfram gives the following: 
$$_2F_1 \left(a,b;\frac{a+b+1}{2};\frac{1}{2}\right) = \frac{\sqrt{\pi} 
 \Gamma \left(\frac{a+b+1}{2} \right)} {\Gamma \left(\frac{a+1}{2} \right) \Gamma \left(\frac{b+1}{2} \right) }$$ and I am struggling to rederive it.

My ultimate aim is to allow the final parameter (the 1/2) to vary. I am fairly certain that the function is increasing up to 1/2, decreasing afterwards, but I am struggling to prove it. Any help in that direction would also be great.
Thanks!

Comment: You can't derive it because it is wrong. According to http://dlmf.nist.gov/15.4.E28
the LHS should be
$$_2F_1 \left(a,b;\frac{a+b+1}{2};\frac{1}{2}\right)$$

Comment: Sorry, yes, a typo. I was trying to derive the correct version, I just typed in the wrong thing here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a derivation of your formula using a transformation and the 
[Gauss's Hypergeometric Theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GausssHypergeometricTheorem.html). The quadratic transformation
http://dlmf.nist.gov/15.8.E18
$${_2}F_1 \left(a,b;\frac{a+b+1}{2};z\right)={_2}F_1 \left(\frac{a}{2},\frac{b}{2};\frac{a+b+1}{2};4z(1-z) \right)$$
gives

$${_2}F_1 \left(a,b;\frac{a+b+1}{2};\frac{1}{2}\right)={_2}F_1 \left(\frac{a}{2},\frac{b}{2};\frac{a+b+1}{2};1 \right)$$
With the well known Gauss's Hypergeometric Theorem
$${_2}F_1\left(a,b;c;1\right)=\frac{\Gamma\left(c\right)\Gamma\left(c-a-b\right)}{%
\Gamma\left(c-a\right)\Gamma\left(c-b\right)}.$$
you get 
$$
{_2}F_1 \left(\frac{a}{2},\frac{b}{2};\frac{a+b+1}{2};1 \right) =
\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{a+b+1}{2}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{a+b+1}{2}-\frac{a}{2}-\frac{b}{2}\right)}
{\Gamma\left(\frac{a+b+1}{2}-\frac{a}{2}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{a+b+1}{2}-\frac{b}{2}\right)}$$

$$
{_2}F_1 \left(\frac{a}{2},\frac{b}{2};\frac{a+b+1}{2};1 \right) =
\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{a+b+1}{2}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}
{\Gamma\left(\frac{b+1}{2}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{a+1}{2}\right)}$$

$$
{_2}F_1 \left(\frac{a}{2},\frac{b}{2};\frac{a+b+1}{2};1 \right) =
\frac{\sqrt{\pi}\;\Gamma\left(\frac{a+b+1}{2}\right)}
{\Gamma\left(\frac{b+1}{2}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{a+1}{2}\right)}$$

Since $4z(1-z)$ has a maximum for $z=\frac{1}{2}$ the first formula should be
a good starting point for your conjecture, "that the function is increasing up to 1/2, decreasing afterwards".

Comment: Thank you very much! I have a question about this:
1. The first transformation requires that $Re(z)<1/2$, whereas here it is exactly 1/2. Why is this still OK?

Comment: Interesting qeustion. I got the formulas from Abramowitz/Stegun and used the DLMF link for easy reference. A/S write that the formula(s) are valid for $0\le z <1$, see the end of section 15.3 at http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_561.htm

Comment: Thank you! If I post the larger question I am working on, do you think you might have 2 minutes to take a look? Hopefully a direction will be clear to you quickly. This area is quite foreign to me.